# dotnetcore Extract Zip Artifact and deploy

Tags: continuous-integration, .net-core, tfsbuild, release-management

I am trying to publish my zipped artifacts using VSTS. It is a dotnetcore application so i used the following documentation to `Publish Build Artifacts`.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/ci/build-aspnet-core

And it works great, but i am having difficulty trying to figure out how to deploy it to an folder on my self hosted server.

In the past i normally just i just copied the files over. By selecting the Source and target folder.

Now i think i first have the unzip it and then copy it?
After the build process my artifacts are dropped in

**$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build step "Extract Files" to unzip your archive. 
After that you can use the step "Windows Machine Copy" to publish your artifacts to your web server.

A better way is to do it via Release Management. I would publish the artifacts with the step "Publish Build Artifacts" to a build drop location. If this done you can do the deployment steps in Release Management. "Extract Files" -> "Windows Machine Copy"

Comment: I am currently using the step to publish build artifacts and do the drop location. Ill look for the windows machine copy. I normally just use the copy files step. Is that the same?

Comment: Not really, Machine Copy is for copy files on a machine. You can use credetials and the execution account (agent account) has to be an admin. Publish Artefacts can ony copy to a unc path.

Comment: ah I figured out what the problem was, i never set the Agent. so it was running on Hosted instead of the one that i created. Fail

Comment: @R4nc1d Glad to know that you have solved the issue, could you please post your workaround as the answer and Mark it as Answer, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: @Andy will do just have not had chance yet. Had to make sure that it actually worked before i posted my answer.